# Extracting text inside "[[ ]]" in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which contains text inside parenthesis. I need to extract text present inside "[[ ]]" parenthesis using Java. Also, there are multiple occurrences of "[[ ]]" parenthesis. I would like to extract text from all of them.

For example:

```
    String text = "[[test]] {{test1}} [[test2]]";
```

Expected Output: 
test
test2

Can anyone help please?

Comment: regex can do this --- so, what have you tried?

Comment: What should happen with a string like `"x [[foo[[bar]]baz]] y"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple regular expression match:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[.*?\\]\\]");
```

Use a `Matcher` with `lookingAt()` method to get the result.

To remove the "[[" and "]]" after that, just add a `String#replace()`.

Comment: @sarghau `Matcher` doesn't do anything to the string.  It just tells you what it found, and where.  You can use things like `start()` and `end()` on the `Matcher` to find out where it found the pattern, and then use `substring` on the original string to get the information you need.  Or use groups as the others are saying.

Comment: You can either do a `String#replace` for that, or add groups to the pattern. In your case, there needs to be only one group. This is already demonstrated in Casimir's answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
String text = "[[test]] {{test1}} [[test2]]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[(.*?)]]", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text); 
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.print(m.group(1));
}
```